# AWS Lambda function with .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to write a .NET Framework (not .NET Core) lambda function?

I have a legacy WCF SOAP service that is not compatible with .NET Core. I know I can write a .NET Framework application and deploy to EC2. Is it possible to deploy a .NET Framework application to AWS in a more scalable/serverless way such as a lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is no built in support for the legacy .NET framework, all available runtime and version are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html).

If you wanted to run a framework/language that is not included on this list your best option is to look at building a [Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) containing the packages you require.

Other than this your only option would be to deploy it to another service, if you can package it into a container then you could run it on [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) (which is a serverless container orchestration service).

Comment: Are there any examples of a .NET Framework Lambda Layer you have seen?

Comment: Not from what I have seen unfortunatelly there are for other languages such as PHP: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-lambda-custom-runtime-for-php-a-practical-example/